# Insert space in comment feed in IOS app

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, comments, ios-app, ios-app-feed

Comments in the IOS-app (Version 1.4.1) feed are identified with a **Comment** *immediately* followed by the actual comment:

[image]

This can greatly benefit from inserting a space.

Comment: This is almost definitely a bug! :)